# динамический IP

Tags: apache, ip

Привет всем! Вот хотел настроить Денвер так, чтобы мой Апаче стал видим в глобальной сети. Как я понял, это возможно, если айпи адрес НЕ является динамическим, а у меня 3g мобильный интернет, соответственно и адрес динамический. Все? На этом конец? Или есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы сайт был виден по IP или по доменному имени?

Comment: По доменному имени

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть еще вариант:  клиент - vds --(vpn)-- комп из локальной сети. в интернете полно примеров. в таком случае обходится ограничение на серые ip.

Answer (score 1):

А как насчёт [DynDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS)? Динамический IP по идее не проблема, лишь бы он был "настоящим", то есть не из-за NAT.

Вот [целый список](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/).